# What are locked files (already inside Trash)?

Tags: macos, trash

I was cleaning my desktop and I put a lot of unnecessary files into my Trash. In one particular folder I was asked to provide administrator's password, so I did. Everything went to Trash very smoothly. Below prompt appeared when I decided to empty Trash.

[image]

- What are locked files?
- What locked them?
- Why those files have been locked?

After clicking on ***Remove All Items*** the trash **was successfully cleaned** however I would like to get answers for those questions.

Answer (score 1):

A locked file can be a lock placed on a file by a process to ensure that the file is available while the process is running. In a second form a lock file has a user defined lock in the file's inode metadata.